# Live usb + Msi GT780/GT683

Tags: boot, msi

I'm trying to install ubuntu, on my new laptop (GT683), but at boot from an usb live ubuntu, the boot freeze at USB HID.
(see "screenshoot" [here](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=952148P13011214410001.jpg))
What can I do to bypass this problem ?

Thank you.
Cyrbil.

Comment: what boot options have you tried?  N.B. as soon as you see the purple screen press any key/escape and then F6 to see the boot options available to you such as noapic, nolapic, acpi=off etc.

Comment: I haven't try any options for the moment, just basic normal default boot.
I try old ubuntu cd (10.6) and work fine. I juste have to update system after. I don't see why last live cd doesn't work ...

Comment: Did you eventually get around this and what did you do? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

fossfreedom has the right idea in his comment on Jan 14.

Following the link at http://forum.notebookreview.com/msi/584869-official-msi-gt780-gt783-owners-lounge-477.html#post8130754, I found I could boot in if I set certain options in my BIOS and also had the following boot options:

```
noapic noacpi nomodeset acpi=oldboot
```

Add them before the -- in the boot options.  You will have to also edit your GRUB config after you install, to have GRUB boot with the options above-- details at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132.

The original poster in the first link does not know whether all of these options are necessary, and neither do I.  If anyone knows specifically which of the above settings are the one(s) that are required, perhaps you can improve this answer.

Comment: Just digging a bit more, I'm wondering if nomodeset is the one that is really needed.  According to http://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting#nVidia_GfxCards, Kernel Mode Setting, which is on by default in Debian-based distros, is incompatible with some drivers for the GFX cards.  The MSI GT780 has a GTX card, I think, but perhaps it has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

What program have you used to install ios file on usb drive? I have not had any problems using [Linux Live](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) USB (Lili). Run Windows up date and the like. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I used Lili. My problem is located on linux usb boot.

Comment: all right, I have boot problems with certain distros -- such as Backtrac. What ISO are you using? Have you entered BIOS and changed the settings to boot USB device first?

Comment: Pc start booting on the device, just some hardware wasn't recognize and freeze all the linux start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my gt683. Solved it by removing the hardware raid partition. Press ctl-I on boot, remove the raid partition, and reboot/install.